# Do PostSharp and .net demon play well together?

Tags: postsharp, redgate

I got the .Net Demon trial from RedGate and it seemed to be working great, but I just realized a PostSharp aspect I'm using is being ignored and I'm not sure why... wondering if it has to do with the fact that they both do stuff with the build system.

Is anyone else using them together successfuly?  I'd like to buy .Net Demon, but not if my PostSharp stuff won't work, of course.  Not sure if it's related or not yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (SharpCrafters) do not officially support .NET Demon. Since Demon is an incremental compiler and PostSharp does not support incremental compilation (it compiles the whole assembly every time), I doubt it could work and, if it worked, I doubt it would have any effect on performance. Since the build time is typically dominated by PostSharp, reducing the time of the C# compiler would not significantly reduce your complete build time.

Comment: Thanks.  FYI, its purpose isn't to reduce the actual build time though.  It just causes it to build continuously as you make changes.  I used the trial and it was amazing... I could run my apps within a a few seconds of hitting F5 instead of often having to wait 2 minutes while it built everything.  However, PostSharp is a little more important to me so you win this one.

Comment: Well, I should say I don't know that it reduces the build time... maybe it does.  But the main thing is that it's always building while I work.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Demon compiles the whole assembly each time it compiles, including any post-build steps that are in the .csproj. I don't see why it shouldn't work. Look in the build output to see whether any logging normally produced by PostSharp is there.